# How to query the effective permission of sql login (windows and/or sql user)?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, sql-server-2019

How to query the SQL server to fetch the effective permission of the following SQL logins under the Security/Logins:

1. SQL user
2. Windows user
3. Windows group

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system view [`sys.server_permissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to query for all server level permissions (which would include permissions assigned to **Logins**). If you join it to the [`sys.server_principals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) system view, you can get information about the **Login** itself as well.

Example from the aforementioned docs:

```
SELECT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc,   
    pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name   
FROM sys.server_principals AS pr   
JOIN sys.server_permissions AS pe   
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id;
```

You may also be interested in the system view [`sys.database_permissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to query for database specific permissions for any database **Users** associated with those **Logins**.